# Force RSpec 3 to show diff for single line strings?

Tags: ruby, rspec, diff, rspec3

I am comparing long strings containing html and not containing new line characters.

According to this ( https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/diffing ), RSpec will diff multi-line strings but will not diff single-line ones.

Is there a way to override this and have it diff one-line strings, too?

I am using RSpec 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no this isn't possible". The longer answer is, it is possible but you will need to write a [custom matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/custom-matchers) which performs the diff. You can format the error message display and have it perform the diff in the style you wish.

Not having diffs for single line[*](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/5) strings was a conscious decision by RSpec[**](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/541).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that when diffing long lines, the whole line is shown as the diff so this would not be very useful. I will consider to break the output into multiple lines and test it that way.